# Is it required to generate java classes to use spring-ws client

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

I want to use spring ws to create the webservice client. I have seen some documentation.
In all using jaxb marshalling and unmarshalling. But to start of need to create java classes from xsd. I tried to download the elcipse plugin for this. The location in java.net is not showing any thing to download. Sourceforce net showing the link to download. But that plugin is not working. I have tried `wsimport`, but it is generating only .classes?

My question is if i want to use spring ws, is it required to generate .java classes? If so where can i find the elipse plugin or how to generate the classes? Is there any other way we can do without generating these classes?

If you use jboss, use `wsconsume.bat` to generate these classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring-WS lets you work with several different representations of the message payloads, JAXB is just one of them. You can also use (for example) raw DOM objects if you choose, or a few other options.

If you already have a WSDL, then `wsimport` should so the job nicely, it generates `.class` files for your schema. You don't *need* the `.java` files also, strictly speaking, you can develop just fine without them, and Spring-WS has no use for them. It *is* easier if you have them, though, and `wsimport` has `-keepgenerated` flag (or something like that) that stops it deleting the `.java` files once it's finished.

Comment: Yes. using -keep option with wsimport generating .java files also. Thank you. May i know what are the other ways to use spring-ws and best way. Here i dont want to deal with raw xmls.

Comment: @vishnu: JAXB is the best option, in my opinion. If if works for you, then stick with it.

Comment: Thank you. I am using JAXB and jboss server I am getting class loader issues like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class [org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler] does not implement the NamespaceHandler interface while running this Client. May i need to post separate question or edit in this Questions it self?

Comment: I have posted one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542471/spring-class-loader-issues-in-jboss-while-using-spring-ws-client. Thank you

Comment: If we use jboss, better to use wsconsume.bat to generate webservice classes to avoid other XML issues.

Comment: i've found XmlBeans to be a nice library to generate class files from your schema.  Spring-WS has an OXM implementation for XmlBeans.