# Spring class loader issues in Jboss while using spring-ws client

Tags: spring, jboss, classpath, classloader, spring-ws

I have my application running properly in Jboss. To to write spring webservice client, i have generated classes using `wsimport`. I have written following in configuration

```
 <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
<property name="messageFactory">
    <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"/>
</property>
```

in jboss?lib i have `jboss-jaxws.jar,spring.jar`...Now i copied

```
spring-ws-1.5.0.jar and  saaj-impl-1.3.jar
```

but i am getting follwoing errors:

```
The Spring ContextLoaderListener we wrap threw on contextInitialized.
But for our having caught this error, the web application context would not have initialized.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class [org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler] does not implement the NamespaceHandler interface
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class [org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler] does not implement the NamespaceHandler interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:119)
```

Please help me to resolve this error. These errors i am getting only after keeping these jars. But these required to run my new code. Please suggest me how to avoid them?

Comment: What versions of java and jboss are you running? And is there a reason you're using Spring WS 1.5.0 instead of the current 1.5.9?

Comment: I am using java 1.4, jboss 4.2.3, spring 2.0.7. No reasons. Just i want to be compatible with my spring. Because of spring version, i am now using Spring ws 1.0.4. to avoid these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file for your application with next content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 4.2//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_2.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
        <loader-repository>
                   myapp:loader=anyUniqueName
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
        </loader-repository>
    </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

This should prevent classloader from looking for JBoss libs. As a downside you'll have to provide all your 3rd-party jars in a WAR/lib folder.

This works for 4.2 you could lookup something similar for version you currently use.

Comment: Thank you.Yes. By copying them to war/lib folder this problem is not appearing. If i copy spring-ws.1.5.0.jar in jboss/lib folder then only this problem occuring. How can i know what other jars confliting this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This suggests to me that there are two versions of that JAR in your CLASSPATH - perhaps one on the server itself and another that's deployed as part of your app - and they aren't the same version.  The server class loader will find the server version first, before your application class loader runs.  If it's an earlier version than required by your app you'll have a problem.

The solution is difficult, because you might not be able to remove the server version without compromising other deployed apps.  See if there's a flag in the JBOSS configuration for your application to tell JBOSS to prefer JARs loaded by the application class loader and see if that helps.

http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/jboss5/jboss5_deployment.htm
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoadingUseCases

Comment: What are the configuration files i need to check to see this