# What is Spring Webservice version to use for Spring 2.0.7

Tags: spring, spring-ws

Is Spring Webservices (Spring WS) supported by Spring 2.0.7? If so what is the version for Spring WS to use?

If not what is spring version i need to upgrate with out much changes of my code.

Please help me i am doing lot of replacement and lot of class loader issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-WS 1.5.x was designed to run with Spring 2.5.x, but I understand that it *can* be made to work with Spring 2.0.x (or perhaps only certain features work).

To be safe, you should use Spring-WS 1.0.x. Or upgrade Spring.

If you choose to upgrade Spring, be aware that Spring-WS 2.x is imminent, and requires Spring 3.0.x.

Comment: Thank you Very Much. This worked. My Spring version is 2.0.7. I have written new Webservice Client using Spring WebServices,JAXB Marshaller. So now i have copied these jars spring-ws-core-1.0.4.jar, spring-xml-1.0.4.jar,spring-oxm-tiger-1.0.4.jar,spring-oxm-1.0.4.jar which is equavalent to spring-ws-1.5.5-all.jar. As we are not able to upgrade Spring version, i am going with these 4 jars. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: This is link to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542471/spring-class-loader-issues-in-jboss-while-using-spring-ws-client. If i keep spring ws 1.5.x. jar in jboss lib, it is running all namespace issues. Now i replaecd this single jar with other 4 jars in jbos/..lib folder. It is working without any issues. Thank you